# Right triangle $ABC$ has $AB=7, BC=24,$ and $CA=25.$ Circle $O$ is tangent to AB and BC and its center lies on CA. Compute the radius of $O.$

Tags: geometry

Right triangle $ABC$ has $AB=7, BC=24,$ and $CA=25.$ Circle $O$ is tangent to $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC},$ and its center lies on $\overline{CA}.$ Compute the radius of $O.$ Express your answer as a common fraction.

Since circle $O$ in tangent to $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$ doesn't that mean $\overline{AC}$ is the diameter of the circle, and the radius is just $\dfrac{25}{2}$? I'm pretty sure that's wrong though, since this is one of the last questions on the homework and the last ones are usually the hardest. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

$\triangle AGD \sim \triangle ABC $

So, $\frac{AG}{AB} = \frac{DG}{BC} \implies \frac{7-r}{7} = \frac{r}{24}$

That gives $r = \frac{168}{31}$.

Comment: ohh i understand how to do it now! thank you so much! this answer was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you call $F$ the center of the circle, $D$ the foot of the perpendicular from $F$ to $BC$ and $E$ the foot of the perpendicular from $F$ to $AB$, then $FEBD$ is a square with side equal to the radius of the circle. Call the radius $r$.

The triangles $FCD$ and $AEF$ are similar. Then
$$
\frac{r}{24-r}=\frac{7-r}{r}.
$$
Solving the resulting linear equation you get $r=\frac{168}{31}$.

Answer (score 0):

The diameter of the circle is not $AC$.
[image]
Say the circle meets $AB,BC$ at $E,F$ respectively. Let the centre of the circle be $G$. Then$$\text{ar}\triangle ABC=\text{ar}\square EGFB+\text{ar}\triangle AEG+\text{ar}\triangle GFC\\\frac{7\times 24}2=r\times r+\frac r2(7-r)+\frac r2(24-r)$$giving $r=168/31.$

Answer (score 0):

The circle with diameter $AC$ intersects line $AB$ at both $A$ and $B$, and intersects line $BC$ at both $B$ and $C$. So, it's not tangent to either of those lines.

A circle tangent to $AB$ and $BC$ must have center lying on the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$. Can you use this to see where the circle should be centered, and from there calculate its radius?

Answer (score 0):

No. The center is the intersection of the right angle bisector and the hypothenuse $AC$.

$AD:DC=AB:BC$

$$AD:DC=7:24\to AD:(AD+DC)=7:(7+24)\to AD:25=7:31\to AD=\frac{175}{31}$$

Triangles $ABC$ and $AHD$ are similar because $DH\parallel BC$. So we have

$$DH:AD=BC:AC\to DH:\frac{175}{31}=24:25\to DH = \frac{168}{31}$$
[image]